# I have no WEB-INF folder in my Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jdbc, web-inf

I`m a newbie in Java. Trying to run a web-app connecting with mysql DB. I know how to add mysql jdbc driver into my bulid-path and I have done it, but I get runtime:

```
Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

it doesn`t appear during compiling procedure, but the moment I refresh the page of web-app it occurs.

The idea is to put my .jar mysql driver into `/WEB-INF/lib` but ***I don't have such a folder***. at all. and everything has been working (it is the Vaadin tutorial example actually with Customers), and I just wanted to add some stuff from DB there. I have another console app in the same workspace and it works with DB and with the driver perfectly. But here. I guess I have to put the .jar into that folder but I have none.

Comment: ...then create the folder and put the jar.

Comment: Maven?  Make it a dependency-

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, thanks! I did it, SOLVED! I had to figure out how to add dependencies to Maven project and then how to deal with "wrong time zone on mysql server" error. But it`s just another story )